# Find records created in last 3 months in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

Below is the query to get the numbers of agents created in each month in last three months.

```
agents_per_month = Agents.where("created_at > ? AND created_at < ?", Date.today.at_beginning_of_month - 2.months, Date.today).group("date_trunc('month', created_at)").count
```

The result output is as follows:

```
{2020-07-01 00:00:00 UTC=>75, 2020-08-01 00:00:00 UTC=>31}
```

The issue with the above result is that since the last third month had no agents created so it doesn't show any value. But I want it to show result in the order as below:

```
{2020-06-01 00:00:00 UTC=>0, 2020-07-01 00:00:00 UTC=>75, 2020-08-01 00:00:00 UTC=>31}
```

So if a month doesn't have any value it should show 0 rather than no value shows up for the particular month.

Please help me resolve this issue.

Comment: Do you want an activerecord solution only, or you would consider a pure SQL query?

Comment: @GMB active record solution

Answer (score 1):

You can join to a [`generate_series`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html) table using PostgreSQL:

```rb
class Agent < ApplicationRecord

  def self.totals_in_last_three_months
    joins("
      RIGHT JOIN generate_series(
        date_trunc('month', statement_timestamp() - interval'2 months'),
        date_trunc('month', statement_timestamp()),
        interval'1 month'
      ) as months(month)
      ON date_trunc('month', agents.created_at) = months.month")
      .group('months.month')
      .count('agents.*')
  end

end
```